# Removing whitespace in inline-block with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to remove the white space between inline blocks with this Javascript code.

```
$.fn.removeSpace = function(){
this.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
};
$('.Container').removeSpace();

<div class="Container">
  <div class="what">
    <ul class="lolers">
      <li class="lol">Test</li>
      <li class="lol">Test 2</li>
      <li class="lol">Test 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I set `$('.Container')` to `$('.lolers')` the whitespace is striped correctly. If it's set as `.what` it wouldn't strip it either.

Edit: Sorry for not including the question. How can I make the javascript code go through everything and strip out whitespaces?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It's a scoping issue.  If you want to do that, you might as well just set the original query to: `this.find('li')`, otherwise you're looking for a recursive DOM transversal.

Comment: Suggestion : remove it with css.

Comment: @drinchev – Or with HTML comments, even.  No need to go crazy with JavaScript here.

Comment: I agree with everyone and suggest that you use CSS for this.  However, if you have to use JS, just use the `replace()` function.  Put document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.`replace(" ","");` all on one line.

Comment: There are some issues with CSS and possible bugs documented on css-tricks.com I was thinking of using javascript for the time being and when the website is ready for deployment to use a html compressor to strip away the unnecessary white space and remove the debugging code. Using Html Comments or any other html trick would break IDE's code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** It was pointed out to me that the font-size: 0; method has some on Safari and Android. I was pointed to this article http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

You can also make them blocks and float them left. Here's my fiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanjsfiddle00/a4nu8arz/6/

html

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

css

```
div div {
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    }

#second {
    clear: left;
}
```

**ORIGINAL POST:** Why use javascsript to remove the white space? As I understand it when you make elements display as inline-blocks the parent element leaves room for text. Basically, what I've read is that images are displayed this way and so inline-blocks default to leaving room for caption text. Set the parent element's font-size to zero. Here's my fiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanjsfiddle00/a4nu8arz/2/

html

```
<div id="first">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

css

```
div div {
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
    #first {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Matt Stow reports that the font-size: 0; technique has some problems on Android. Quote: "Pre-Jellybean does not remove the space at all, and Jellybean has a bug whereby the last element randomly has a tiny bit of space." This was taken from css-tricks.com

Comment: Yeah, that's where I read about font-size zero. Well, I guess just make 'em blocks and float them left instead. Here's my fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/ivanjsfiddle00/a4nu8arz/6/